# Showing only specific attributes from xml in ListView Android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am trying to show the names of some items in my list and on click, I should show more, maybe even be able to update/edit the contents. My activity xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_list_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#035E7B"
    tools:context="com.example.melisaam.logintest.ListItemsActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/sections" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my array xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="sections">
        <item>
            <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$5.95</price>
            <description>
                Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
            </description>
            <calories>650</calories>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$7.95</price>
            <description>
                Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
            </description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$8.95</price>
            <description>
                Belgian waffles covered with assorted fresh berries and whipped cream
            </description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>French Toast</name>
            <price>$4.50</price>
            <description>
                Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread
            </description>
            <calories>600</calories>
        </item>
        <item>
            <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
            <price>$6.95</price>
            <description>
                Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns
            </description>
            <calories>950</calories>
        </item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Currently I'm loading my items this way in my activity:

```
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create the list activity");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_items);


        //* *EDIT* *
        this.listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

But this is not very great. All my attributes are put in one row from my list. I want in my listview to appear only the name and the price and on click, additional info should appear. Any ideas how I could do this without having xml parsers or is that the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own list view layout, and map it through a list adapter. And also from what I understand, you need `ExpandableListView`, to show more items when pressed.